# ASP.NET Execute SQL Server stored procedure multiple times async

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql-server, stored-procedures

I am calling a stored procedure via ASP.NET now I am trying to call it 200 times async, I am trying to do this by adding a transaction, however its not working out, here is my code:

```
try
{
    using (connection = new SqlConnection(connectionString))
    {
        connection.Open();
        transaction = connection.BeginTransaction();

        for (int i = 0; i < 200; i++)
        {
            using (SqlCommand command = new SqlCommand("TimeSlotAppointments", connection))
            {
                command.Transaction = transaction;

                command.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;

                SqlParameter parameter1 = command.Parameters.Add("@StartTime", SqlDbType.DateTime);
                parameter1.Direction = ParameterDirection.Input;
                parameter1.Value = DateTime.Now;

                command.ExecuteNonQuery();
            }
        }

        transaction.Commit();
    }
}
catch (SqlException e)
{
    Console.Write(e);
    transaction.Rollback();
}
finally
{
    connection.Close();
    connection.Dispose();
}
```

I am passing the current date and time as a parameter and when I check out the results in SQL Server I am expecting the `@StartTime` to be the same, but they are not, close, but the milliseconds increase for each record, am I going about this the wrong way? What I am trying to accomplish is executing the store procedure 200 times simultaneously.

Comment: If you want the DateTime to be the same for all records then store the `DateTime.Now` in a variable once outside the loop and use it for `parameter1.Value`.

Comment: why would you expect `@StartTime` to be the same, when you call `DateTime.Now` 200 times? time passes ... However: what is this code actually trying to do? it seems unlikely that you'd want to run the exact same SQL with the same parameters - 200 times. Also, you're not actually calling it async ("now I am trying to call it 200 times async")

Comment: I have a feeling this is an XY Problem. https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem

Comment: What does a transaction have to do with async? A transaction is used to do the *opposite*. Force multiple concurrent commands to run in sequence

Comment: If you want to execute the same sproc N times, create the sproc once then *change* the parameter value N times: `for (i=0;i<200;i++){parameter1.Value=someNewValue;cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();}`. A *better* solution is to avoid the loop entirely. What does the sproc do and why don't you pass all the values you need at once?

Comment: You have to be careful when you use the phrase 'async'. 'async' could also mean the async framework which does not do simultaneous execution. You want simultaneous execution which means you want multi-threaded execution (by the way, you won't be able to spawn 200 threads and have them ALL run at the same time as there are hardware limits to that). If you want the same start time, store the current DateTime outside of the loop as others have said. If you want simultaneous execution, check this link: https://www.codeproject.com/articles/1030252/multithreading-in-csharp-net-part

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The start time value is different because you are assigning the value **inside** the loop and in every iteration, the time has changed (a few milliseconds as you mentioned). If you want to use the same value for all calls, then you need to store the time stamp outside the loop in a variable and use that value in your loop. 
This is how your code should look like:

```
try
{
    using (connection = new SqlConnection(connectionString))
    {
        connection.Open();
        transaction = connection.BeginTransaction();
        var startTime = DateTime.Now; // I added this line 

        for (int i = 0; i < 200; i++)
        {
            using (SqlCommand command = new SqlCommand("TimeSlotAppointments", connection))
            {
                command.Transaction = transaction;

                command.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;

                SqlParameter parameter1 = command.Parameters.Add("@StartTime", SqlDbType.DateTime);
                parameter1.Direction = ParameterDirection.Input;
                parameter1.Value = startTime;  // I changed this line

                command.ExecuteNonQuery();
            }
        }

        transaction.Commit();
    }
}
catch (SqlException e)
{
    Console.Write(e);
    transaction.Rollback();
}
finally
{
    connection.Close();
    connection.Dispose();
}
```